How to apply Postfix milter *before* smtp_generic_maps for DKIM purposes?
My Postfix instance instance correctly signs outbound mail with DKIM when I set the myhostname parameter to be the domain I wish to send from, say domain1.com.
The issue I have is I have multiple domains. To ensure outbound mail has the correct From field, I use smtp_generic_maps to rewrite myhostname to my desired domain, say this time it is domain2.com.
In my current setup, it seems that smtp_generic_maps applies its rewriting after any milters have been applied. In the case of the OpenDKIM signing milter, this breaks the encryption. So, how can I reverse the order so that my domain name is rewritten before DKIM signing is performed ?
Alternatively, how else could I rewrite my From address field before DKIM is applied, if not using smtp_generic_maps ?
Help is appreciated.
OS Specs: I am using Ubuntu, version Focal Fossa.

ran into the same issue tonight. did you ever find a reliable solution for this?

Hi alternize, yes I did ! Off the top of my head I can't recall what it was. I don't have free time currently, though I may get a moment this weekend where I can fill you in. I will add an answer with what I do recall, and edit it once I look into it again. Please let me know if it helps.

I have looked into my solution and found the following:
First, an overview:
To achieve the desired result, for each username-domain pair, I create a unique UNIX system user.
In viewing my set-up, I use both a postfix functionality, and an OpenDKIM functionality, to map from these system usernames to the desired email addresses. I am not clear if both, or only one of, these functionalities is required. I don't currently have my notebook with me, which I likely documented the case in. However, if in experimenting you find the answer, please pass on what you find.
Second, some specifics:

I note the name associated with my mail server. This is specified in the postfix configuration file by the 'myhostname' parameter. To create an example, assume:

myhostname = serverdomain.com


Create postfix mapping:

------a) Specify a file to contain the mapping in the postfix configuration. This is achieved using the 'smtp_generic_maps' parameter. Example:
smtp_generic_maps = texthash:/absolute/path/to/generic

------b) The format of this file is the UNIX system username, followed by the @ symbol, followed by the server domain name. Next comes a space. Finally, we list the desired email address we wish to appear as the mail origin. Specifically, every UNIX username will map to a certain email address. Continuing the example:
username1domain1@serverdomain.com username1@domain1.com
username2domain2@serverdomain.com username2@domain2.com 


Create OpenDKIM mapping:

------a) Similar to step (2) above, we set the file location for mapping. This is specified by the OpenDKIM 'ReplaceRules' parameter in the OpenDKIM configuration file. Example:
ReplaceRules = /absolute/path/to/ReplaceRules

------b) The format of this file is identical to step (2)(b) above, with the exception that the two columns are separated by a tab, instead of a space character. If I recall correctly, separating by a space will not be read correctly. Example:
username1domain1@serverdomain.com    username1@domain1.com
username2domain2@serverdomain.com    username2@domain2.com 


As I mentioned in my overview, I am not sure if both steps (2) and (3) are required, or whether only one of the 2 steps is necessary. My suspicion is that only the OpenDKIM step is necessary. Please fill me in if, through implementation, you find a definite answer.

Process Summary

A user passes a message to postfix
Postfix maps the users name to an address via the 'generic' mapping file, discussed above.
Postfix passes the message, appearing to come from the address, to OpenDKIM
OpenDKIM substitutes the address to the desired address, according to the the ReplaceRules file discussed above.
OpenDKIM encrypts the email.
OpenDKIM passes the message back to postfix
Postfix sends the message to the internet

NOTE: Reiterating, I am not sure if both of, or only one of, steps (2) and (4) are necessary.
Apologies for the formatting. With any luck, someone may update the appearance, if it is possible. Please let me know if this description is helpful.
